# Android : Preview multiple screen densities

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-density

Is there any way in Android Studio, to preview multiple screen densities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are preview modes for layouts, where you can select device screens, in which you will preview your layout.

Also there was introduced new preview screen in [Android Studio 2.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html)

Answer (score 1):

When previewing your layout click the device selector from the toolbar and select a device with a density you want to test.

[image]